# RestKit: How to preprocess JSON value before mapping

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

Currently I am using the following JSON format which is a snippet from SharePoint REST service:

```
{results:[
   {uri:"https://site.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'43963c38-4d1c-4734-8b2d-22dc0b92908c')"},
   {uri:"https://site.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'5363c738-7d9d-9774-6b2d-52dc0b93903d')"}]
}
```

And I have the following object mapping:

```
RKEntityMapping *listMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"SPList" 
    inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[listMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"uri":      @"guid"}];
listMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"guid"];
```

However, before saving to guid, I would like to add logic to retrieve only the guid part from uri before saving, so only "43963c38-4d1c-4734-8b2d-22dc0b92908c" is stored in guid field. I don't know where to add that logic, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to change the returned JSON before mapping it, you can use an implementation of RKSerialization:

```
@interface ORRKJsonSerialization : NSObject <RKSerialization>
@end
```

and implementing

```
@implementation ORRKJsonSerialization

+ (id)objectFromData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)error
{
    id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:error];
    // change your data before mapping
    return result;
}

+ (NSData *)dataFromObject:(id)object error:(NSError **)error
{
    return [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:object options:0 error:error];
}

@end
```

then during the setup:

```
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[ORRKJsonSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"application/json"];
```

HTH